# Копирование данных из поля по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Есть кнопка и поле под ней с автоматически генерируемым кодом. По нажатию на эту кнопку или на поле, код в поле должен копироваться в буфер обмена. Информация в поле должна быть недоступна для редактирования. Как такой блок реализуется, есть ли он в бутстрапе (сам найти не смог, хотя на самом сайте используется сплошь и рядом)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
     $('#code')[0].select(); 
     document.execCommand('copy');
     $('#code').append(' ');
     $('#code').val().slice(0, -1);
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {width:250px;height:80px;resize:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="code" readonly>I love this code</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Копировать">
```